# Сover на музыку скаченный с сайта

Tags: php, изображения, музыка

Здравствуйте.
Хотелось бы когда пользователи скачивали с моего сайта музыку(.mp3) на него добавлялся cover(водяной знак) фото. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Даже и его в музыки и нет. Я видел это в нескольких сайтах. Можно ли организовать это думаю это пишеться через php но я front end  и не разбираюсь в этом) Спасибо всем за ответы

Comment: Вам нужна библиотека, которая умеет работать с [ID3 метаданными](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)) треков не ниже версии ID3v2. Стандартная библиотека такого не умеет, там только до ID3v1, поэтому ищите сторонние библиотеки PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C помощью библиотеки [getid3.sourceforge.net](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/), примерно:

```
$data = [
    'attached_picture'=>[
        0=>[
            'description'=>'My best music',
            'mime'=>'image/jpeg',
            'data'=>file_get_contents('Path/To/Image.jpeg'),
            'picturetypeid'=>0x03
        ]
    ]
];

$writer = new \GetId3\Write\Tags;
$writer->filename = "path/to/music.mp3";
$writer->tag_encoding = 'UTF-8';
$writer->tagformats = ['id3v2.3', 'id3v1'];
$writer->overwrite_tags = true;
$writer->tag_data = $data;
if ($writer->WriteTags())
    echo "Тег успешно обновлен\n";
else
    throw new \Exception(implode(' : ', $writer->errors));
```